# Get songs From windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I am trying to copy songs from windowsphone8 media library. I was able to get the list of songs. Can we copy Song as stream?
Are there any APIs available right now?

Answer (score 0):

Converting a media library song into its equivalent stream is not possible as Microsoft.Xna.Framework.MediaLibrary.Song is a sealed class, and there are no provisions given in the class to convert it into an equivalent stream. [This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd254868) link very well explains the structure and methods/properties available to a user

You can use reflector and make your own working Song Class But again, that's a big pain.

Answer (score 0):

Applications do not have access to the raw stream/audio content of songs in the media library. [Here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/wpapps/en-US/02089afb-5597-414c-9862-a5f58d368fad/read-song-path-andor-raw-data-from-media-library?forum=wpdevelop) are more discussion about this topic.